# Where can I spend Monero?

Tags: merchants

Is there an available list or directory of Merchants that accept Monero?

Is it true that Monero can be spent at any business that accepts Bitcoin? If so how does the process work and which service providers facilitate the XMR/BTC exchange?

Comment: I don't think it's a good question, since it looks like it will attract opinions.

Comment: I think it'll attract lists more than opinions. It is pretty open ended though.

Comment: @nicael I modified my question asking for a list/directory of Monero merchants and clarified the Bitcoin merchant question

Comment: You seem to be asking about two distinct topics, they should be split into different question posts.

Comment: @murch I agree. I deleted the question and will narrow the scope for the question replacement(s)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a growing list of merchants that accept Monero below, although the list may not be comprehensive:
https://getmonero.org/getting-started/merchants

Any business that accepts Bitcoin can be paid with XMR.to which automatically converts Monero from the buyer into Bitcoin that will promptly be sent to the Bitcoin merchant.

Shapeshift.io offers a similar service to xmr.to but with slightly slower payments (they wait for tx confirmations instead of scanning the mem pool like xmr.to) but slightly higher maximum transaction sizes.

Payment processors such as BitPay and and wallets (such as Exodus) are starting to integrate Shapeshift. Riccardo Spagni has a payment processor in development named PayBee.

Comment: i also recommend xmr.to and shapeshift

Comment: additionally one should not forget that you can get a VPN directly via Monero at cryptostorm.is/cryptostorm.org/ works flawlessly so far